# button face for setting default value (e. g. speed)

Tags: buttons, icons

In a user interface, push buttons are used for increasing and decreasing a value. Is there a commonly accepted/comprehensible button face that indicates return to the (non-zero) default value?

So far I am using

[image]

though I am not sure whether the meaning of the button in the centre is obvious.

Comment: The meaning of the button in the middle is not obvious: it could set the value to the median or the average. For a better icon I suggest you try somewhere like https://thenounproject.com/ and search for 'default' and it's synonyms. Here, however, icon suggestions tend to be opinion based and vary from culture to culture so are considered off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind buttons like this is to take away any cognitive load. It should be as obvious as possible to the user what these buttons are for, I agree that the middle button isn't clear.

I'd suggest inserting the word 'reset' in it's place. This is on the presumption that there is enough space for this.

Maybe add in your question what device/platform this is aimed at, you'll get some clearer answers off people on here.

**EDIT**:
To reply to your comment, try using the classic reset icon

[image: Reset Icon]

This icon is well known to symbolise the resetting of an action, when placed in between two other icons such as yours, it will show the user that this is for the purpose of resetting the previously made actions.

Comment: Thank you for this. I want to avoid textual hints. The buttons shall be used for changing playback speed of a media file in a web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tackle this challenge would be to use a range slider instead the button. As you are increasing or decreasing the values one by one, I would think that the range would not be that large, in which case the range slider values could also be limited while in the middle there would be the Zero value (or whatever default value you have).

Certainly if the values are being imported dynamically and there are many range types this could be a bit of a tackle.

Please see the attached image.

[image]

Comment: This solution is not viable for large ranges and the OP explicitly stated that the default is non-zero.

Comment: Thank you William! I have also stated "or whatever default value you have". The image is just an example.